# Constructor generics issue

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I am making a little text based game for fun and i'm messing around with generics and have run into an issue.

I have a class Equippable:

```
public class Equippable extends Item
{
    double mDurability; 

    public Equippable(String name, double weight, double durability)
    {
        super(name, weight);
        mDurability = durability;
    }//Equippable

    //Getters
    public double getDurability(){return mDurability;}

    //Setters
    public void setDurability(double Durability){mDurability = Durability;} 
}//Equippable
```

I have a constructor for a class called BodyPart that I want to accept any subclass of Equippable as a parameter:

```
public BodyPart(String name,  Class<? extends Equippable> equipClass)
{
    mName         = name;
    mEquipClass   = equipClass;
}//BodyPart
```

Equippable has a subclass Armor.

```
public class Armor extends Equippable
{
    double mArmorRating;

    public Armor(String name, double weight, double durability, double armorrating) 
    {
        super(name, weight, durability);
        mArmorRating = armorrating;
    }//Armor
}//Armor
```

Finally I have a couple classes that extend Armor.class. I won't post them all as they are identical at this point except for the name of the class.

```
public class HumanoidBodyArmor extends Armor
{

    public HumanoidBodyArmor(String name, double weight, double durability, double armorrating) 
    {
        super(name, weight, durability, armorrating);
    }//HumanoidBodyArmor
}//HumanHeadArmor
```

When I do:

```
BodyPart bp = new BodyPart("Head"  , Armor.class));
```

everything is fine, and the object is created. However when I do

```
BodyPart bp = new BodyPart("Head"  , HumanHeadArmor.class));
```

Eclipse throws a fit and says

```
The constructor BodyPart(String, Class<HumanoidHeadArmor>) is undefined
```

I was so sure this would work but apparently I am missing something. Can somebody shed some light on the subject?

Just for sanity I did

```
Equippable.class.isAssignableFrom(HumanoidHeadArmor.class)
```

and it did indeed evaluate to true.

**EDIT**
As requested in the comments, here is the HumanoidBodyArmor class

```
public class HumanoidBodyArmor extends Armor
{

    public HumanoidBodyArmor(String name, double weight, double durability, double armorrating) 
    {
        super(name, weight, durability, armorrating);
    }//HumanoidBodyArmor
}//HumanoidBodyArmor
```

There is no difference between headarmor/bodyarmor/footarmor. Thy are all identical besides the name. Just empty classes with identical constructors that just call their parent's (Armor) constructor.

Comment: HumanHeadArmor or HumanoidHearArmor? Could you please show the code of both classes?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak The *relevant code* only...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 classes with the same name in your classpath? Otherwise, I don't see any issue with your code.

Comment: @m0skit0 The code I asked for is more relevant than anything else. It's new BodyPart("Head", HumanHeadArmor.class)); that doesn't compile.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I mean not the full classes, only the relevant code from those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all works fine for me - I suspect you have some naming issue.

```
class Item {

    public Item(String name, double weight) {

    }
}

public class Equippable extends Item {

    double mDurability;

    public Equippable(String name, double weight, double durability) {
        super(name, weight);
        mDurability = durability;
    }

    //Getters
    public double getDurability() {
        return mDurability;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setDurability(double Durability) {
        mDurability = Durability;
    }
}

class BodyPart {

    String name;
    Class<? extends Equippable> equipClass;

    public BodyPart(String name, Class<? extends Equippable> equipClass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.equipClass = equipClass;
    }
}

public class Armor extends Equippable {

    double mArmorRating;

    public Armor(String name, double weight, double durability, double armorrating) {
        super(name, weight, durability);
        mArmorRating = armorrating;
    }
}

public class HumanoidBodyArmor extends Armor {

    public HumanoidBodyArmor(String name, double weight, double durability, double armorrating) {
        super(name, weight, durability, armorrating);
    }
}

public void test() {
    BodyPart head = new BodyPart("Head", Armor.class);
    BodyPart body = new BodyPart("Body", HumanoidBodyArmor.class);
}
```

Comment: Woooow I suck. I guess Eclipse spoiled me. The class didn't get imported. Probably because of my wonky package structure that I have been messing around with.

Comment: @0nyx hehe and that's why it's good to stick to a standard package/project structure. :D

Comment: @0nyx - I often find building a simple demo of the problem as completely separate test code - I use inner classes for compactness - allows you to find the silly mistakes before you suffer the embarrassment of posting them online. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `generics` correctly

To start with, `Equippable` should probably be an `interface` rather than a class, and `Armor` can also be an `interface` that extends `Equippable`

Then you can have

```
public class BodyPart {

    public BodyPart(String name,  Equipable equip)
    {
        mName         = name;
        mEquip   = equip;
    }
}

and

public class Head extends BodyPart {
    public Head(String name, HumanoidHeadArmor equippable) {
      super(name, equippable);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that a better use of generics?

Comment: Would you care to elborate (if possible, I realize typing essays in the comments is frowned upon) on why I am using generics incorrectly? I was trying to avoid things like being able to equip a sword on a body. I felt like I could accomplish this by only allowing a bodypart to have a certain type of item equipped on it. So if I create an arm, I give it an equipClass as a parameter, then I can test to see if an item is allowed to be equipped by testing if it is a subclass of that equipClass.

Comment: @0nyx gonna create a new answer to address your question